# Ford-Fulkerson appears to not work on this graph

Tags: algorithm, max-flow

My analysis of the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm is not coming out correctly. For example, take the following graph:

```
      _____>4___>_
     |            |
0--->1---->3------6
|    |            | 
2--->5--------->---
```

Node 0 is source, node 6 is the terminal node, and every edge's restriction is 1, except edge from node 0 to 1 's restriction is 2. If the flow goes from 0->1->3->6 and 0->1->4->6 and 0->2->5->6, the  flow of the graph is 3. However, if the flow start from 0->1 choose to go from 0->1->3->6, and 0->1->5->6, we cannot go from 0->2->5->6 anymore, since 5->6 has already been occupied. Since 0->1's restriction is 2, we can only start from 0->1 twice, therefore, the flow of the graph is 2.  Obviously, the max possible flow of the graph should be 3 not 2. Will the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm handle this problem and always return 3 as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Ford-Fulkerson can. Always solving such problems is actually what it was designed for.

I guess the fact you are missing is that when determining the residual graph you also have to add the back edges. Thus after  going  0->1->3->6  and 0->1->5->6 the residual graph actually looks like this:

```
                1          1
            +-------> 4 ------+
            |                 |
        2   |     1        1  v
  0 <------ 1 <----- 3 <----- 6
  |         ^                 |
  |   1     | 1               | 1
  +-------> 5 <---------------+
```

The next step Ford-Fulkerson is going to take is adding the route 0->5->1->4->6 thus yielding a flow of 3.

Answer (score 0):

It will timeout when the maxFlow is too high. (In the worst case Ford fulkerson adds only 1 flow at each step)

Just use BFS instead of DFS in ford fulkerson and it becomes [Edmonds carp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm)! Its too fast and widely used compared to Ford-fulkerson.

You can also check out the PFS(Priority first search) which is explained [here](http://help.topcoder.com/data-science/competing-in-algorithm-challenges/algorithm-tutorials/maximum-flow-section-1/).